# iOS:Objective C - Sqlite query to get records which has comma separator values in where clause

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, where-clause

In my database I have records which have a column with comma separated values like below:

[image]

I want those records which has `RoomNo = 121` only.

If I use query

`select ID,RoomNo from RoomTable WHERE RoomNo = 121`

OR

`select ID,RoomNo from RoomTable WHERE RoomNo LIKE '%121%'`

It only returns one record:

[image]

But I want row no 8, 10, 11 in output. I tried with `SET, regexp` also but no luck.

Please suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: Redesigning your database so it's properly normalized with each row referring to a single `(id, room)` pair would be the best solution. Read up on many-to-many relations.

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in an earlier comment, the best way to do this is with a proper database design - instead of a row like `(11, '12,121,20')`, have three rows `(11,12)`, `(11,121)`, and `(11,20)` so a simple `WHERE roomno = 121` can be used. Storing your data in a way that the RDBMS is designed to work with is so much easier than what you're doing, which is trying to force a square peg into a round hole.

However, if you can't fix your data for some reason... a comma separated list of numbers is *very* close to a JSON array of numbers, and sqlite has [decent support](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) for working with JSON...

So, given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE rooms(id INTEGER, roomno TEXT);
INSERT INTO rooms VALUES (9, '108'), (11, '12,121,205'), (12, '12,205')
                       , (16, '121'), (17, '121,205'), (20, '205');
```

this query

```
SELECT *
FROM rooms AS r
WHERE 121 IN (SELECT j.value FROM json_each('[' || r.roomno || ']') AS j)
ORDER BY id
```

gives you

```
id          roomno    
----------  ----------
11          12,121,205
16          121       
17          121,205
```

Answer (score 0):

This Should be working

> select * from RoomTable where RoomTable.roomID like '%121%'

As you can see in Image. And Please show your code also to know more about issue.

[image: RoomTable]

[image: Query]

Comment: This will not work 100% in case i have roomId like 1210 OR 11210.

Comment: Another way is get all record with this like query and when you map your data to object that time manually compare it if it's contain what you want or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a project set up with SQLite, but quick searching shows it supports RegEx (Regular Expressions).

You can give this a try:

```
select ID,RoomNo from RoomTable WHERE RoomNo REGEXP '(?<!\d)(121)(?!\d)'
```

That says: all records where RoomNo contains 121 *not* preceded (negative look-behind) or followed (negative look-ahead) by a DIGIT, so it *doesn't* match `1121` or `1210`, but it *will* match `121,` or `, 121` or `121` by itself.

Here is a RegEx tester of that https://regex101.com/r/aS8jQ8/27

**Edit:** As noted by "Shawn", this will not work "out of the box." And, I don't know if a REGEXP function can be supplied in iOS.

Comment: The keyword is `REGEXP` not `REGEX` and it's not supported out of the box. An extension or language bindings or a program has to supply a user defined function by that name that does the matching.